# I want to print first name last and second name first in python

Tags: python

```
name=''.join(list(map(str,input())))
```

I want to use the above input method and print print first name last and second name first in python.

For example I want to print Tom Hardy as Hardy Tom.  How can it be done?
Thank you

Comment: store your first name and last name in diff variable and use string concatenation :) but first try at least and then reach to SO\

Comment: I used that method and got answer. I was just wondering if it can be done using input like this.

Comment: name=''.join(list(map(str,input())))
print(name[::-1]) Output - tom hardy
ydrah mot

Comment: And I am trying this method because sometimes in a coding platform you have to accept many string in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` method already returns a string, doesn't make sense to apply `map(str,)` on it.

You'd better split and reverse the order

```
name = " ".join(reversed(input("What's your name: ").split()))
print(name)
```

Or maybe easier, but fails it you don't enter exactly 2 words

```
first_name, second_name = input("What's your name: ").split()
print(second_name, first_name)
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.